# Not found gradle 3.1.2

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I'm trying to run my react-native project ( react-native run-android ) and I get this error:

```
 Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.jar
```

Any help?

Comment: I am also facing this problem, but can't solve this. Did you solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

add `google()` to repositories in your project build.gr